# vim snipmate - use a variable multiple times in a snippet

Tags: vim, snipmate

sometimes I need to use a variable multiple times in a snippet. For instance, when I need to set a key-value list:

```
${1}_key: ${1}_value
```

I hope the cursor can stop at the first `${1}` when I trigger snipmate in this case. When I input something like `foo` at the first `${1}`, it can become

```
foo_key: foo_value
```

Thus, I need to input `foo` only once. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's easy:

```
${1:}_key: $1_value
```

Comment: Why is the colon required at `${1:}`?

Comment: Frankly, I don't know. (Maybe I knew it before, but I can't remember it now) But I want to say Hi to you. I saw your ID before. Thanks for letting the world know the shitty things happening in China :)